# RadioButton-CheckBox Combo

Tags: java, android, radio-button

For my particular application, I want to be able to toggle a radiobutton on and off by touching it, similar to a checkbox. However, I need the radiobuttons to be mutually exclusive within their groups. There are 64 buttons and 8 groups, so I don't want to use checkboxes and program the toggle functionality manually. Can I use an `onTouchListener()` with a radiobutton? Is there any way to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: RadioButtons are, by their definition, mutually-exclusive within a group. I don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: I want to be able to touch a radiobutton and have it uncheck, similar to a checkbox.

Comment: But if you use a radio button group, one or  other button is supposed to be enabled at all times. The correct way to have no buttons enabled would be to have an extra radio button within that group called 'No selection' or similar.

Comment: This is not, in any way shape or form, a normal android application. The user is not making choices, they are triggering audio samples with the radio buttons. I want to be able to shut off the sample by touching it again, but not shut off all the samples at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a UI paradigm that is neither a checkbox nor a radio button. Your best bet is to use check boxes and then implement the mutual exclusivity on top of that. e.g.,

```
myCheckbox1.setOnCheckChangedListener(new OnCheckChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      myCheckbox2.setChecked(false);
      myCheckbox3.setChecked(false);
      myCheckbox4.setChecked(false);

      // start playback
    } else {
      // stop playback
    }
  } 
);
```

Note that if you are able to enumerate all of the button IDs per group, you can write the code generically, like,

```
    if (isChecked) {
      int myGroup = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); // Define the group in the view's tag
      for (int id: groups.get(myGroup)) {
        if (id != buttonView.getId()) ((CompoundButton) findViewById(id)).setChecked(false); 
    }
```

The other, more complicated answer would be to build your own UI widget and give it whatever semantics you want. That's not scope of what I could describe here though.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help, but as I mentioned, I have 64 buttons distributed into 8 groups. It would be highly inconvenient to do it manually.

Comment: you don't have to do it manually. if you have the buttons in arrays, you can just loop turning off all but the selected button. it's a few lines of code. regardless, you aren't going to get what you are looking from a radio button.